# JavaFX Check-Menu-Item Css: Change Mark color on focus

Tags: css, javafx

That´s what I currently have:

http://s1.postimg.org/44h3mt0rj/check_menu_item_mark_color.png

and the css

```
.check-menu-item:checked
{
    -fx-mark-color: rgb(207, 178, 125) ;
}

.check-menu-item:focused
{
    -fx-mark-color: black ;
}
```

The first one works just fine but the second one not.

What´s wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check `modena.css`, then on focus, `-fx-focused-mark-color` property is used to paint the tick instead of `-fx-mark-color`.

You can use the same for your css :

```
.check-menu-item:focused
{
    -fx-focused-mark-color: black ;
}
```